# Is it on-topic to ask for information/references on a person?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

I am looking for references or information of a person who published a book about Christianity and Finance in 1932, in London. This person was from the military, achieving lieutenant-commander rank.

I am not sure this is on-topic though. On the one hand, the person is not purely a "common citizen". But on the other hand, it might be too specific and of little interest to others. What is the policy about this here? It is not clear to me when reading the tour page. Would there be another site more appropriate for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the limited information you provide, I'd be inclined to treat it as on-topic.  Legitimate topic of historical research.  You might want to explicitly state that this is not geneology - there is a geneology stack and we try to respect their boundaries.

But research on a historical personage should be legit.  IMO.